# MFC Multithread Raw Data Viewer Program Design

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, udp

The program I'm working on has the following features:

- Display the incoming data (thru an ethernet UDP socket)
- Manipulate and calculate some data in the header and display
- Save a # of frames upon user input

The program has the following structure:

- a Main UI thread running (provided by MFC)
- a thread which takes the dialog itself, *this*, as a parameter and is in charge of receiving the data through the UDP socket
- a thread which also takes the dialog pointer, *this* and is in charge of displaying the data

The data receiving thread is using a buffer to store data and the buffer is a member of the dialog class. What makes this possible is, in the display thread, I can access the data stored in the buffer with the use of the dialog pointer and display it; such as StretchBlt(....., pdlg->vbuf[0].data, ....);.

It really isn't much complicated. The program runs smooth until there is a user input (windows messages, or more). It crashes at:

1. Most frequent crash point

```
CEXAMPLEAPP::InitInstance()
{
...

CEXAMPLEDlg* pdlg = new CEXAMPLEDlg;
m_pMainWnd = pdlg;
INT_PTR nResponse = pdlg->DoModal(); <--------------------------------------------
if( pdlg!=NULL )
{
  delete pdlg;
  m_pMainWnd = NULL;
}

...
}
```

nResponse turns out to have a huuuuge negative value (something like 19 decimal degits) which I don't think is a normal behaviour.

2. It also crashes at a couple different locations. Most of them are reading violations or dll errors which are hard to interpret and track the cause.

I have done some research, the possible causes of the crashes are:

i) The dynamically allocated dialog object is a local. Therefore the allocated memory isn't enough to process the infinitely incoming data. That's why it's causing reading violations at random locations.

ii) Another possible cause is that most of the variables, including the frame buffers, are member variables - the program is using two separate worker threads and they all are taking the dialog pointer as a parameter. Even though the reading and the writing to the buffer routine are done within CCriticalSection lock(), and unlock() inside the thread functions (global), the variables' ownership could be the possible cause.

This is where I'm at right now. Any ideas to fix the crashes? Any thoughts on using the variables as member variables of the dialog class?

- The threads are communicating through SetEvents() and WaitforSingleObject() btw.

Comment: GUI programming is hard to do threaded. It's usually the thread that creates the UI components and which have the main message loop that "owns" all components. Do all UI handling in one single thread, and use other threads for data processing or other I/O (network, file, etc.).

Comment: Drop the POSIX-mentality. I/O in Windows is asynchronous by default. That allows you to keep everything on a single thread. [`CAsyncSocket`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/casyncsocket-class) conveniently encapsulates the complexities of asynchronous I/O for you.

Comment: As for the crashes: They are the result of you no longer understanding the runtime structure of your program. A rather common consequence of throwing threads into the solution space.

Comment: Why ever set the `theApp.m_pMainWnd` member yourself? It is set be framework and points to a `CFrameWnd` or `CDialog` (for a dialog-based app) instance, belonging to the main (UI) thread. All UI items should best belong to the main thread as well. You can choose an asynchronous or multithread-based solution. The main thread should display the data received/prepared by the worker thread(s). It would vastly help if you define one (or several) global "state" variable, eg Idle, connecting, connected, pending-I/O, data-received etc, and perform operations or enable/disable UI items based on that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you display the data (`StretchBlt(....., pdlg->vbuf[0].data, ....);`) in the display thread and this is accessing the display DC, you have to make sure you are doing it in sync with the main thread, for example, by using atomic locks. Or as an alternately better solution, do the display in main thread and remove the display thread altogether.

Comment: Accessing the same DC from different threads may not produce the desired result, but will not ever provoke an access violation exception. See [Thread affinity of user interface objects, part 2: Device contexts](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20051011-10/?p=33823).

Comment: @IInspectable , the link you gave, say this:
" If you choose to use a DC in a multi-threaded manner, it’s your responsibility to coordinate the consumers of that device context so that only one thread uses it at a time. "

Comment: Yes. That's what you need to do if you are looking for predictable results. It is not something you need to do to guard against access violation exceptions. That's taken care of for you by the system already. And since the question is asking specifically about access violation exceptions this proposed answer does nothing to provide an answer here.

Comment: @IInspectable , unpredictable results is very common to end with access violations usually after due to buffer overrun or stale pointers.

Comment: There aren't any stale pointers involved, or even pointers at all. Device contexts are identified by ID, not a pointer. The system verifies whether the ID (encoded as `HDC`) is valid or not. It will not *ever* produce an access violation exception.

Comment: @IInspectable , we don't know how far he goes in his codes. He hints that he's doing bitmap editing, and that's done in the display thread.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that this proposed answer is factually incorrect. Now clearly the OP gets their lifetimes wrong, but none of that has anything to do with device contexts.

Comment: @IInspectable , he can easily change the size of his HBITMAP at the same time when the main thread is accessing the HBITMAP to stretchblt to the display DC. That certainly is gonna raise an access violation

Comment: One cannot change the size of an `HBITMAP` without creating a new one. Creating a new `HBITMAP` has no effect on the previous `HBITMAP`, so there's not even a data race here. Even if an `HBITMAP` is destroyed while it is being used by a different thread, that's not going to cause an access violation either.

Comment: @IInspectableyes, change the HBITMAP to a different size i mean. Well i don't know what causes my program to crash then, when i did that. It never crashes when I sync them with locks